# Show custom image in Mac OS Mojave Dashboard

Tags: macos, mojave, dashboard-widget, widgets

I really like the Dashboard overlay in Mac OS Mojave. Can I add a widget to show an jpg image in the dashboard?

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can open an image in Safari (even from your disk, by drag'n'drop) and click on `File`->`Open in Dashboard...`.

Check the result and if it's not satisfying, resize the image and redo the operation.